# Zsh alternative for Bash

Tags: command-line, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

Can someone tell me the zsh command for `vmstat` ? Also is there any link that lists out all these zsh equivalents? I keep stumbling upon this problem all the time when I'm trying to do something. Thanks

Comment: vmstat would be the same in zsh and bash, I would think.  Perhaps it's not on the $PATH variable?

Comment: `~ % vmstat
zsh: command not found: vmstat`. This is what I get.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not on the machine.  Go into bash and type `which vmstat `.  That will show you the full path to the executable.  Try running that instead in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

`vmstat` is the same in both shells (and all shells), you probably just don't have your `PATH` set correctly.

**The Fix:**

In your bash terminal (just type `bash` to open the bash terminal) type: `which vmstat`, you should see a path return.

Now, append this to your PATH in your `.zshrc` file with:

```
OUTPUT="$(which vmstat)";echo "export PATH=\""${OUTPUT}":\$PATH\"" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Switch to zsh by typing: `zsh`

Now source your `.zshrc` with:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Your `PATH` should be corrected.

**Optional:**

If you have just switched to zsh and you had a simple `.bashrc` file, one thing you could do is move everything from your `.bashrc` to your `.zshrc`. Just run:

```
cat ~/.bashrc >> ~/.zshrc
```

This will append everything in your `.bashrc` to your `.zshrc`.

Now source your `.zshrc` with:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Your `PATH` should be corrected, but you may want to manually example your `.zshrc` file for redundancies.